# Activate SSL Namecheap with EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, namecheap

I have a website on an EC2 service from AWS. The web domain was purchased on Namecheap with SSL protection. I was investigating how to activate this ssl protection. The first thing I did was to generate the CSR code from my EC2 instance. Then I went to Namecheap to use this code and activate the SSL Protection. I complete the DCV validation using the "HTTP-based validation". Now in my Namecheap main panel the SSL certificate says to be active. But when wanting to go to my website, it still does not appear. Is there something I need to do? Thank you all for your time!

Comment: To the person that down voted this question. Take the time to add a comment so that new people can learn how improve their questions or why you think the question deserves a down vote. Just down voting does not help anyone. IMHO, this question is just fine.

Comment: @JohnHanley I can not speak about the others but I downvote because: 1) it lacks any details (with the website name people could have tested) and it seems specific to some providers and 2) for me it is off-topic as not related to **programming** but more about configuration.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - Good points. How is the OP to know this unless we help them to understand by providing suggestions? However, to downvote this question when there are so many other similar questions is not right. I prefer just to help the new guys get started. If they stick around, they will understand how everything works on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnHanley I disagree, accepting bad questions just because there are already other bad questions is not ok. Otherwise it means as soon as one case slips through the crack then everyone is welcome to post anything irrespective to the topic? And not to be naive, not everyone comes here to really participate, some people create an account asks a very specific question for only their very specific case, and then never come back (often do not validate the answer even if it helped them)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - another suggestion. Instead of just down voting questions, I would like to see comments first to suggest how to improve the question. If the OP does not improve their question, then down vote. I am also opposed down voting without a comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley as for not knowing: in Tour you have "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." (which should clearly mean: say which website you are talking about) and various points in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask hints to the same thing.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I do not feel that this question is a bad one. I understood instantly what he was asking and what the answer is. How about wee spend our time helping others instead of criticizing.

Comment: @JohnHanley A downvote is another form of feedback, just as comments. The OP is notified of it, so it could as well come back, reread its question, think about what may be wrong or even ask.

Comment: Wow - we all have to read the owner's manual before asking for help.

Comment: @JohnHanley "How about wee spend our time helping others instead of criticizing. " I am not criticizing I just have the opinion that this a bad question because it lacks details and is offtopic. That is all. Everyone else is free to agree/disagree/upvote/downvote/comment/reply...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I am not referring to you as you added a comment that was helpful. I am referring to the blind down votes with no comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley "Wow - we all have to read the owner's manual before asking for help." Indeed you are supposed to take the tour of the website before using it, and reading the FAQ never hurts... Of course if you are in an hurry just to get the solution to your tiny specific problem, then you do not care, you post and wait for a benevolent soul...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I do agree with you. Some people do take advantage of Stack Overflow. I also think that there are a few malcontents that just like to censor people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to install the certificate and private key on your web server. You will also need to setup / enable HTTPS on your web server.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/795/14/how-to-install-ssl-certificates

Comment: Thanks to you! This was what I needed to do, it worked perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome. You will (usually) find Stack Overflow a great place to find information to help solve problems and improve your skillset. I use Stack Overflow every day to research information. There are some really talented people here.

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand your question clearly but try this and see if it helps - add this to your web config file

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<clear />
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" 
redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is a suggestion after the OP gets HTTPS and SSL working. This will redirect HTTP to HTTPS which is a good idea. Note; the OP has not indicated which web server he is running so the method of redirects needs to be considered.